# bootstrap columns overlapping sidebar and table

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have an issue with bootstrap's grid layout. My columns are overlapping one another

I'm not sure what the issue is.

Here is a picture of what is going o[image]n:

here is my code
[image]

Comment: Please provide your code by copy-pasting it into the post; not as an image. So, other users can easily read your code

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).